# unable to add product in shopping cart in magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, error

```
require_once '../../app/Mage.php'; 
umask(0);  
Mage::app();

Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customerID);

$params = array(
    'product' => $productIds,
    'qty'     => $p_qty,
    'price'   => $price
    );

$_product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($productIds);    

$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();

$cart->addProduct($_product, $params ); -->error
```

==>error on above line.

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Please specify product link(s).' in /app/Mage.php:594 
Stack trace: 
#0 /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php(284): Mage::throwException('Please specify ...') 
#1 addcart.php(54): Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->addProduct(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 1) 
#2 {main}
```

Comment: You are trying to add a downloadable product to the cart ? Share the whole script, what is in $_product and what is in $params ?

Comment: i just edited that question please check.

Comment: Are you trying to add one or many items?

Comment: I just try only one item to add in magento 1.8 through php script.

Comment: Check what parameters default Magento use when dealing with the downloadable products. You'll need to replicate that. The method you are using is used for simple products without any custom options.

Comment: need to add product in shopping cart with current login customer or gust customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
require_once '../../app/Mage.php'; 
umask(0);  
Mage::app();

Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customerID);

$_product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($productIds);  

$params = array(
    'product' => $productIds,
    'qty'     => $p_qty,
    'price'   => $price
);

if ($_product->getTypeId() == 'downloadable' && $_product->getLinksPurchasedSeparately()) {
    $linksArray = array();
    $links = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getLinks($_product);
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        $linksArray[] = $link->getId();
    }
    $params['links'] = $linksArray;
}

$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();

$cart->addProduct($_product, $params );
```

Comment: spealing mistake here downnloadable change to downloadable and &_product to $_product .. thanks for save my days very helpful.

Comment: Book Type
E-Book: 100/- 
Print Book: 200/- there are two link(e-book and print book) how could i identify is this e-book or print book in $link.

Comment: you could check link title: $link->getTitle();